# Jira soap api: Retrieving issue list belonging to a project

Tags: php, soap, jira

I am working with jira 3.13.x, soap and php; and i need to retrieve the issue list under a project. is it possible? 
And secondly can the issue keys be searched for a specific search term. if its possible please elaborate

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at [this open source project](https://github.com/csharptest/JiraSVN/wiki) in C# for more info:

Comment: ok, thank you for the reply, i got the desired issues with the help of getIssuesFromTextSearch method from the jira soap services, but i have realized that the retrieved issues are of the closed status. how can i get the issues with the desired status,i.e. open, in progress and reopened